# jQuery datepicker use getXMLHTTP()

Tags: jquery, ajax, onchange, xmlhttprequest

I want to get the datepicker value to change the selected option value. So I must use an event like onchange to change the next value. But jQuery does not support onchange. How can I do this?

```
function gettime(str) {

            var strURL="/Doctor/booking/gettime.jsp?datepicker="+str;
            var req = getXMLHTTP();

            if (req) {

                req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (req.readyState == 4) {
                        // only if "OK"
                        if (req.status == 200) {
                            document.getElementById('datepicker').innerHTML=req.responseText;
                        } else {
                            alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                        }
                    }
                }
                req.open("GET", strURL, true);
                req.send(null);
            }
        }

 <b>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" readonly="true" change="gettime(this.value)"></b>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            maxDate: '+1m',
            minDate: 'Now',
            beforeShowDay: noSundays
        });
    });
});
function noSundays(a) {   a=a.getDay();   return[a>0&&a<7,""]; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have jquery included in your page and do AJAX the way we did it in 1999 when Microsoft first introduced the XMLHTTP ActiveX object in Internet Explorer 5? I cannot believe my eyes.

So, let's do this by taking advantage of what the framework we are using has to offer to us and get rid of this `gettime` function:

```
<b>
    Date: 
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" readonly="true" />
</b>
```

and then:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            maxDate: '+1m',
            minDate: 'Now',
            beforeShowDay: noSundays,
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Doctor/booking/gettime.jsp',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: { datepicker: $(this).val() },
                    success: function(result) {
                        $('#datepicker').val(result);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });

    var noSundays = function(a) {   
        var day = a.getDay();   
        return [day > 0 && day < 7, '']; 
    };
</script>
```

Comment: the origin url is strURL="/Doctor/booking/gettime.jsp?datepicker="+str; i need the jsp?datepicker. because i will request.Parameter("datepicker"); how can i change the ajax?

Comment: @user1190842, when you use $.ajax and specify `type: 'GET'` jquery will automatically use the `data` variable to format the query string so a request with the expected value will be sent to the server.

Comment: sorry, i can't get the date value beacause it may be jquery.